# Emailing attachments in R via gmail (using jython)

Tags: python, r, email, pdf, jython

I'm trying to send an email with attachments in R through gmail using the jython package. I realize jython is python language within R, the problem is I do not know python, hence hoping someone proficient in that language may be able to help me.

Why am I using jython? Because the other email package that seems popular on SO - sendmailR - does not work with gmail as it requires authentication.

The source code I used is [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Email-out-of-R-code-td3530671.html). As the guy says in the link, the original code is built for emails without attachments. I was able to run this version perfectly with no errors (i.e. able to send emails without attachments via jython in R).

However, when I tried to add some script to include attachments, it didn't work. 
This is my attempt at formatting this code to handle attachments (login/email details blanked out):

```
rJython <- rJython()
rJython$exec( "import smtplib" ) 
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart")
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase")
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEText import MIMEText")
rJython$exec("import email.utils") 
rJython$exec("import smtplib")
rJython$exec("import os")
rJython$exec("from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate")
rJython$exec("from email import Encoders")



mail<-c( 
  #Email settings 
  "fromaddr = '@gmail.com'", 
  "toaddrs  = '@gmail.com'", 
  "msg = MIMEMultipart('This is the body of the message.')", 
  "msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('', fromaddr))", 
  "msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('', toaddrs))", 
  "msg['Subject'] = 'Monitor'", 

  #SMTP server credentials 
  "username = ''", 
  "password = ''", 

  #Attach file
  "files = 'E:/R/R_Data/output/S.pdf'",
  "msg.attach(MIMEText('Your message contents'))", 

  "for f in files:", 
  "    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')", 
  "    part.set_payload( open(f, 'rb').read() )", 
  "    Encoders.encode_base64(part)", 
  "    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;
  "    filename=\"S.pdf\"' % os.path.basename(files))", 
  "    msg.attach(part)", 

  #Set SMTP server and send email, e.g., google mail SMTP server 
  "server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')", 
  "server.ehlo()", 
  "server.starttls()", 
  "server.ehlo()", 
  "server.login(username,password)", 
  "server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())", 
  "server.quit()") 

 jython.exec(rJython,mail)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in jython.exec(rJython, mail) : [Errno 2] ENOENT: 'E'
```

My understanding is that this error in Python means "no such file or directory".

Things I may be doing wrong:
1. Am I locating the directory of my attachments incorrectly?
2. Is the code not working because I am specifying only one single file in the directory to attach?
3. Can the code not handle .pdfs?
4. Is some other part of the code incorrect?

Version details:
      platform       x86_64-pc-mingw32
      arch           x86_64
      os             mingw32
      system         x86_64, mingw32
      status
      major          2
      minor          13.1
      year           2011
      month          07
      day            08
      svn rev        56322
      language       R
      version.string R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)

Many thanks in advance for your help. 
A.

Comment: Have you tried the [gmailR package](https://github.com/trinker/gmailR)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENOENT` means [file not found](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) - your code takes just the first character of `files`, which - of course - is not a valid filename. To successfully send an email over Gmail with a PDF attachment using jython, you could use:

```
library(rJython)
rJython <- rJython()
rJython$exec( "import smtplib" ) 
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart")
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase")
rJython$exec("from email.MIMEText import MIMEText")
rJython$exec("import email.utils") 
rJython$exec("import smtplib")
rJython$exec("import os")
rJython$exec("from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate")
rJython$exec("from email import Encoders")

mail<-c( 
  #Email settings 
  "fromaddr = '@gmail.com'", 
  "toaddrs  = '@gmail.com'", 
  "msg = MIMEMultipart('This is the body of the message.')", 
  "msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('', fromaddr))", 
  "msg['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('', toaddrs))", 
  "msg['Subject'] = 'Monitor'", 

  #SMTP server credentials 
  "username = ''", 
  "password = ''", 

  #Attach file
  "files = ['E:/R/R_Data/output/S.pdf']",
  "msg.attach(MIMEText('Your message contents'))", 

  "for f in files:", 
  "    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')", 
  "    part.set_payload( open(f, 'rb').read() )", 
  "    Encoders.encode_base64(part)", 
  "    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='S.pdf')",
  "    msg.attach(part)", 

  #Set SMTP server and send email, e.g., google mail SMTP server 
  "server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')", 
  "server.ehlo()", 
  "server.starttls()", 
  "server.ehlo()", 
  "server.login(username,password)", 
  "server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())", 
  "server.quit()") 

jython.exec(rJython,mail)
```

As mentioned in another answer, you first got to [allow less secure apps to access your Gmail](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Then the result will be:

[image]

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much for your kind help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example with google account and **mailR** package:

```
library("mailR")

mail.from <- "yourmail@gmail.com"
mail.to <- "recipent@gmail.com"
mail.subject <- "subject"

smtp.host.name <- "smtp.gmail.com"  # if you are using gmail smtp keep this
smtp.host.port <- 465               # if you are using gmail smtp keep this
smtp.user.name <- "yourAccountGmail@gmail.com"
smtp.host.passwd <- "yourpass"
smtp.ssl <- TRUE                    # if you are using gmail smtp keep this

smtp = list(host.name = smtp.host.name, port = smtp.host.port,
              ssl=smtp.ssl, user.name = smtp.user.name,
              passwd = smtp.host.passwd)

send.mail(from = mail.from,
            to = mail.to,
            subject = mail.subject,
            body = "BodyText",
            attach.files = c("path/to/your_file.ext"),
            smtp = smtp,
            authenticate = TRUE,
            send = TRUE)
```

Also , first enable  SMTP access for your Google account. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps